# Single server or multiple servers?

Tags: windows

I work for a small organisation with 20 users. We have a Windows Server 2012 machine setup as a domain controller to handle user accounts, file sharing and backups.

I have a separate Windows 7 machine running XAMPP/MYSQL that hosts our internal database.

I want to setup Google Drive to backup 160GB of critical files for an online failsafe backup, as well as for occasional remote access of key files. This will run in the background all day backing up whatever key files are created on a day-to-day-basis.

My question is, should I setup a separate dedicated machine to perform this task, or should I configure either of the aforementioned servers to do this? I'm worried about putting too much load on either machine and causing its primary function to suffer as a result. I'm also conscious that Google Drive doesn't support Windows Server 2012 so installing it on the primary main server would be difficult anyway.

The Database server is only a dual-core machine with 4GB of RAM so not exactly a modern or quick machine.

I'm just worried that having three machines running to perform these different functions is overkill, but at the same time, is it too much for one single machine?

Comment: How busy is the 2012 machine and what's it's spec? If there's plenty of resources left over you could use Hyper-V to virtualise the very small database PC and perhaps even another machine to deal with the google backup work - you could actually reduce the number of machines here!

Comment: "We have a Windows Server 2012 machine setup as a domain controller to handle user accounts, file sharing and backups." And when this machine fails your whole domain goes out of the window. Doable - if a replacement comes fast and you do frequent backups. Otherwise you already need a 3rd machine to have a minimum of 2 domain controllers.

Comment: Monitor CPU usage you can decide if you need to setup a separate machine, You can use Amazon S3 as alternative to Google drive.

Comment: The 2012 machine is an Intel Xeon E3-1220 @3.10Ghz with 16GB of RAM.

At present it's running at 29% memory and only 1%CPU so it has plenty of resources left, which is reassuring. I just don't know how much extra load will be taken up if I switch the DB server to this machine.

Answer (score 0):

You must think about that : If you host multiple backup or backup program on the same machine, how it will repond in attack, failure, problems?
Google drive and local backup are not the same backup, you will lose "only" the difference between them in case of big problem.
You have to choose : a safer backup or a lower cost.

Comment: Google Drive is just a failsafe backup for my primary local backup. I do a full Bare Metal backup daily but a remote backup of key shared files, which my boss likes to be able to access remotely from his phone or laptop.